# Round to nearest hour pd.Timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, time, rounding, timedelta

I am calculating the time worked for the operators, there is a format table:
operator, call accepted like this [image: Source data]
In the cycle I subtract 2-1, 3-2, etc and summarize in variable Time.

```
         if CurrentOperator == list.iloc[i][0]:
             DiffTime = list.iloc[i][1] - list.iloc[i-1][1]
             if DiffTime > pd.Timedelta('46 minutes'):
                DiffTime = pd.Timedelta('0 minutes')
             Time += DiffTime
         else:
```

Result 
[image: Result]

How can I round time to nearest hour? If variable Time have type timedeltas.Timedelta

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas.Timedelta.round(self, freq)`

```
from pandas import Timedelta

time = Timedelta('09:55:49') 
print(time)
```

```
Out[5]: Timedelta('0 days 09:55:49')
```

```
Timedelta.round(time, 'h')
```

```
Out[6]: Timedelta('0 days 10:00:00')
```